# selected attribute is not working on <option> - ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jquery-select2

I'm working with dropdowns and select2, and I need to edit product, and ofcourse that selected product contains a belonging group/category in a dropdown, but that group is not selected when I open modal, even if value is there, here is how I tried to achieve it:

1.) Fill dropdown with all categories (it works)
(`*ngFor="let category of mainGroups`)

2.) Select corresponding value based on selected article (it doesnt work)

```
<!--category-->
<div class="form-category">
  <label class="control-label dash-control-label col-xs-3">Product category:</label>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <select touch-enter-directive [ref]="ref" [nextFocusElement]="articleSubGroup" id="mainGroupSelectEdit" class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;"
            data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" name="mainGroupSelectEdit" required (change)="filterSubById(article.groupId)" [(ngModel)]="article.groupId">
      <option disabled>-/-</option>
      <option [value]="category.id" *ngFor="let category of mainGroups" [selected]="category.id==='a0e25215-a60e-4444-b6ac-4521b7de4b37'">{{category.title}}</option>
    </select>
    {{article.mainGroup.id}} <- here is shown value a0e25215-a60e-4444-b6ac-4521b7de4b37, so I thought that value should be selected in dropdown
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see guys I've used

`[selected]="category.id==='a0e25215-a60e-4444-b6ac-4521b7de4b37'"`

because I thought this might work like this, but obliviously it can not..

Answer (score 0):

You have the model of the select set to `article.groupId`.

It doesn't matter if you use `[selected]` as long as the `article.groupId` remains unchanged.

If you want the option **a0e25215-a60e-4444-b6ac-4521b7de4b37** to be selected, you need to assign the **a0e25215-a60e-4444-b6ac-4521b7de4b37** value to the `article.groupId` property. In this case the ngModel sets the selected attribute as long as it's value is equal to one of the options.

Comment: code example for what? In  your component ts, you need to initialize `article.groupId` to have a value. What value does it currently have?